# Javascript: Duplicate array incorrect after slice and appending keyValue

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out why the `persons` array contains the new `age` key:value pair.
I thought by slicing it (and therefore creating an independent copy) I could work solely on the `newArray` and only append `age` to it ... but it seems to be updating `persons` as well??
Thanks in advance

```js
const persons = [
  { first: 'Albert', last: 'Einstein', birthYear: 1879, deathYear: 1955 },
  { first: 'Isaac', last: 'Newton', birthYear: 1643, deathYear: 1727 },
  { first: 'Galileo', last: 'Galilei', birthYear: 1564, deathYear: 1642 },
  ];

function appendAge(originalArray) {
  var newArray = originalArray.slice(0);

  newArray.forEach(item => {
    item['age'] = item.deathYear - item.birthYear;
  })
  return newArray
}
console.info(persons)
var newPersons = appendAge(persons)
console.info(newPersons)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`slice` does a shallow copy, meaning it only copies the top level of values, including references, and doesn't actually copy the referenced values themselves.

This means each person object in both of your arrays is the same object.

A simple solution would be to create a custom copy function for your person object and use that along with `map` to copy an array.

```js
const people = [
  { first: 'Albert', last: 'Einstein', birthYear: 1879, deathYear: 1955 },
  { first: 'Isaac', last: 'Newton', birthYear: 1643, deathYear: 1727 },
  { first: 'Galileo', last: 'Galilei', birthYear: 1564, deathYear: 1642 },
  ];

function copyPerson(person) {
  return Object.assign({}, person);
}

function copyPeople(people) {
  return people.map(copyPerson);
}

function appendAge(people) {
  const newArray = copyPeople(people);

  newArray.forEach(item => {
    item['age'] = item.deathYear - item.birthYear;
  });

  return newArray;
}

console.info('----------------------------------------');
console.info('Old People');
console.log(people)
console.info('----------------------------------------');
console.info('New People');
console.log(appendAge(people));
```

You can also check out [How do I correctly clone an object in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/how-do-i-correctly-clone-a-javascript-object) for other solutions.

Comment: There's no need to use `.slice()` if you also call `.map()`, since `.map()` creates a new array.

Comment: awesome ... thanks for the super-quick reply ... I'd read a bit about shallow vs deep copy but hadn't really got to grips with it ... this solution is perfect.

Comment: @sigmazen glad to help out :)

Answer (score 3):

You've created a copy of the `persons` array, that contains references to the original objects, and not a copy of those objects. To create a full copy, you'll need to clone the objects as well.

Note that `Object#assign` will only copy the top level properties of the object, so you'll need to [deep clone](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clone-deep) the objects instead.

```js
const persons = [
  { first: 'Albert', last: 'Einstein', birthYear: 1879, deathYear: 1955 },
  { first: 'Isaac', last: 'Newton', birthYear: 1643, deathYear: 1727 },
  { first: 'Galileo', last: 'Galilei', birthYear: 1564, deathYear: 1642 },
  ];

function appendAge(originalArray) {
  return originalArray.map((item) => Object.assign({}, item, {
    age: item.deathYear - item.birthYear
  }));
}

var newPersons = appendAge(persons);
console.info(newPersons);
console.info(persons); // persons haven't changed
```

Comment: Why `Object.assign`, why not simply `originalArray.map( item =>  ( {age: item.deathYear - item.birthYear } ) )` ?

Comment: @DavidDomain because the OP wants to add the `age` as a new property for each copied person, not overwrite the entire person object.

Comment: Ohh, sorry thought only the age is needed in the new array, my bad.

Answer (score 1):

Your .forEach loop is actually what's updating the Array, not the slice.  The slice is making a copy but when you pass it comes into the forEach loop.  So when you're adding your items to what you think is the copy, you're adding to the original.

Comment: I think this answers your question.  I guess I don't see why you'd update a copy.  Maybe you're doing a comparison?  If so, do a deep clone of the original, store it into a variable at init, then at save/update compare orig to updated... just guessing here